# Защита api от чужих запросов

Tags: api

Допустим у меня есть api сервер. Я к нему обращаюсь с приложения написанного на vue js. Любой человек может разузнать ip сервера и обращаться к api. Как можно защитить его от чужих запросов?

Comment: Никак. Любой человек может сделать имитацию vue js приложения, если захочет

Comment: Сделать так, что бы сервер проверял наличие параметра, скажем, `access_token` в параметрах? Создаёте себе ключ из 30 (условно) символов, передаёте его в запросе на сервер (`?access_token=Ad89Hjuw76542LRe852J8L2J710NMBe`). Ключ то, по идее, никто у вас не разузнает, если случайно пакеты не перехватит...
Если речь о полном отсутствии обработки чужих запросов, то никак, вероятно.

Comment: @Don2Quixote перехват пакетов встроен в любой браузер, вообще не проблема

Comment: @andreymal А, точно, речь же о запросах с сайта

Comment: Т.е. любой человек может полностью скачать бд через апи?

Comment: Может, если вы предоставите такую возможность в своём апи

Comment: Даже если бы не было бы никакого api, а данные из БД на сайт попадают в виде уже готовых страниц, то все равно любой человек может получить всю БД сделав парсер страниц (хотя конечно это несколько труднее, чем брать из api).

Comment: Ну насчет таких данных понятно, а вот например данные пользователей?

Answer (score 0):

Никак, но:
 - можно проверять referer.
 - можно установить csrf токены
 - можно сделать автризацию приложения

Comment: Можете скинуть пару ссылок об этом? Был бы очень благодарен